# xCode - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: xcode, frameworks, symbols, mwphotobrowser

I'm trying to use the MWPhotoBrowser project in my project. I followed the whole installation process and was able to import the MWPhotoBrowser.h file. When I tried to build, I run into this error...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhotoBrowser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PhotoBrowserViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting this issue...Please check if you correctly linked your project to the libMWPhotoBrowser.a file under Build Phases in your target settings !

Comment: Also libDACircularProgress.a, libMBProgressHUD.a, and libSDWebImage.a